# Grails hibernate dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I'm having a weird problem, which I cannot solve at the moment.

Today I couldn't start my grails application anymore. The application code hasn't changed, the last week it was running smoothly.

This is the output:

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.3
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 1 source files.
path: /home/jacopo/.grailsApp/xml
| Error Error executing script RunApp: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<clinit>(Dialect.java:113)
  at DataSource$_run_closure1.class$(DataSource.groovy)
  at DataSource$_run_closure1.$get$$class$org$hibernate$dialect$MySQL5InnoDBDialect(DataSource.groovy)
  at DataSource$_run_closure1.doCall(DataSource.groovy:26)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at DataSource$_run_closure1.doCall(DataSource.groovy)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at DataSource$_run_closure1.call(DataSource.groovy)
  at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at DataSource.run(DataSource.groovy:21)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:51)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
  at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
  at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
  at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
  at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
  at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
  at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
  at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
  at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
  at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
  Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: IllegalAccessException trying to instantiate: org.hibernate.type.BlobType
    at org.hibernate.type.AlternativeLobTypes.createLobType(AlternativeLobTypes.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.type.AlternativeLobTypes.<init>(AlternativeLobTypes.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.type.AlternativeLobTypes.<init>(AlternativeLobTypes.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.type.AlternativeLobTypes$BlobTypes.<init>(AlternativeLobTypes.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.<init>(BlobType.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.type.BlobType.<clinit>(BlobType.java:39)
    ... 71 more
  | Error Error executing script RunApp: null
```

I'm a bit lost at the moment.

Maybe someone can give me a hint about where to search for the error/problem.

Comment: try `grails clean` & `grails compile --refresh-dependencies`.

Comment: Already tried that but no success. I'm running it on ubuntu. Might it be for some package that the system updated ?

Comment: If you are using SNAPSHOT dependencies, then application could start to behave differently out of the blue. Keep in mind that SNAPSHOT dependencies are refreshed every 24 hours be default. Maybe this is your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem looks like it is similar to this [one](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10183).

What they suggested is trying with no reloading:

`grails -noreloading run-app`

There are a few other suggestions in the thread as well but the main error I would focus on in the stacktrace is `org.hibernate.HibernateException: IllegalAccessException trying to instantiate: org.hibernate.type.BlobType`